# cardano-node: error while loading shared libraries: libsecp256k1.so.0:

Tags: cardano-node, stake-pool, library

I compiled cardano-node 1.35.3 on another Ubuntu box and copied over, but it seems a library is missing.

```
cardano-node: error while loading shared libraries: libsecp256k1.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

You need to download, compile and install `libsecp256k1`:

```
git clone https://github.com/bitcoin-core/secp256k1
cd secp256k1
git checkout ac83be33
./autogen.sh
./configure --enable-module-schnorrsig --enable-experimental
make
make check
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig
```

Details https://www.coincashew.com/coins/overview-ada/guide-how-to-build-a-haskell-stakepool-node/part-i-installation/installing-ghc-and-cabal

Comment: You might need to reboot after this.

Answer (score 2):

Only took my second node for me to realize there is a line missing from the https://developers.cardano.org/docs/get-started/installing-cardano-node version.  The line below is missing from the docs but you can see it in sunapi386's answer

```
sudo ldconfig
```